# Can a C# property lose its value?

Tags: c#

I'm facing a strange behavior with a C# property. I've a class called `WorkDay` which has a property called `WorkingTime`:

```
class WorkDay : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Time WorkingTime { get; private set; } = new Time();

    public delegate void WorkingTimeChanged();
    public WorkingTimeChanged OnWorkingTimeChanged { get; set; }

    // This function is called when some other properties changed in that same class.
    private void ComputeWorkingTime()
    {
        if ( ... )
        {
            WorkingTime = ...;

            NotifyPropertyChanged("WorkingTime");

            OnWorkingTimeChanged?.Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

In another class called `WorkWeek`, I've a list of `WorkDay` which is modified by a method called `AddWorkDay`:

```
class WorkWeek
{
    private List<WorkDay> _workDays = new List<WorkDay>();

    public void AddWorkDay(ref WorkDay workDay)
    {
        workDay.OnWorkingTimeChanged += WorkDay_OnWorkingTimeChanged;

        _workDays.Add(workDay);
    }

    private void WorkDay_OnWorkingTimeChanged()
    {
        foreach (var workDay in _workDays)
        {
            _actualWorkingTime += workDay.WorkingTime;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that when the `WorkDay_OnWorkingTimeChanged` method is called, the `WorkingTime` property loses its value (the value is still correct in the corresponding `WorkDay` object). I don't know where I'm wrong. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Usually properties don't "just lose their value". As `WorkingTime` has a private setter, I assume somewhere in that class you change the value yourself

Comment: Do not try to guess what is wrong. Place a breakpoint on WorkingTime setter and inspect values and call stack. You will probably find cause in a matter of minutes.

Comment: I can't see why AddWorkDay uses 'ref' keyword - that would suggest that workDay could change value within the function, which it doesn't/can't.

Comment: Now this may be very far fetched but if you are sure that you assign a valid value to `WorkingTime` just before firing the `OnWorkingTimeChanged` event, it may in some **very**  rare occasions that the JIT compiler reordered some instructions there and invoked the event before assigning the value. Again this can happen in extremely rare occasions (I doubt this is one of them) but you could try adding the `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoOptimization)]` attribute to the `ComputeWorkingTime()` and see if that does anything for you. Most likely the bug is somewhere else in your code though...

Comment: What Nikola said. If you need help debugging your code, we'll gladly help you, but we'll need a [mcve]. Make sure it's both *complete* (otherwise we can't run it on our systems) and *minimal* (otherwise people won't bother reading it). Adding a dotnetfiddle link (in addition to posting the code in your question) won't hurt as well.

Comment: What is `_actualWorkingTime `? The calculation you do with this variable seems strange.

Comment: "the value is still correct in the corresponding WorkDay object" - this confuses me. If it is correct in the WorkDay object, where is it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, the problem occurs in the `WorkDay_OnWorkingTimeChanged` but my code wasn't enough complete to help you find the solution:

```
private void WorkDay_OnWorkingTimeChanged()
{
    if (_actualWorkingTime.IsSet())
    {
        _actualWorkingTime.Unset();
    }

    foreach (var workDay in _workDays)
    {
        if (workDay.WorkingTime.IsSet())
        {
            if (!_actualWorkingTime.IsSet())
            {
                _actualWorkingTime = workDay.WorkingTime;
            }
            else
            {
                _actualWorkingTime += workDay.WorkingTime;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, when I do this `_actualWorkingTime = workDay.WorkingTime`, it seems I pass **by reference** the `workDay.WorkingTime` property to the `_actualWorkingTime` attribute. This is why the `workDay.WorkingTime` property can be changed later when I modify the `_actualWorkingTime` attribute.

Comment: Is this an answer to your question? Or a clarification? In the latter case, please [edit] the question. Also, the definition of `_actualWorkingTime` is still missing as well as a clarification what the `Time` class or struct is.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you are initialising WorkingTime as new Time.

This should work as is -

public Time WorkingTime { get; set; }

Comment: shouldn't be an issue in my opinion. All that does is to assign a default value "empty time" to that property. if it were `public Time WorkingTime => new Time()` then you were definitely correct.
I assume that property is initialized elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

WorkDay_OnWorkingTimeChanged return is void it's not returning anything.

And is your app compiling? Because you are missing the the () on the same method